# How to type π (pi) in Java?

Tags: java

Is there a character within the Math API that allows for representing the character `π`?

Comment: Oh sorry, in a JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String) with the pi character in the string. But Louis below has answered it. :)

Comment: The correct character for representing π is of course π itself. Don’t use ugly escapes that confuse people. Just use UTF-8 for your source.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You don't even need to use the Math API. In Java source code, this:

```
\u03C0
```

is equivalent to this:

```
π
```

and you can even use it in an identifier; these two are equivalent:

```
final String \u03C0 = "\u03C0";
final String π = "π";
```

(As the spec puts it:

> A Unicode escape of the form `\u`*xxxx*, where *xxxx* is a hexadecimal value, represents the UTF-16 code unit whose encoding is *xxxx*. This translation step allows any program to be expressed using only ASCII characters.

See http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.2.)

Comment: I didn't know you can use Unicode chars for variables. Ha, that would be a nice way to annoy my coworkers

Comment: Just enter it in real UTF-8. You have to compile with -encoding UTF-8, but so it goes. At least now it can be read.

Comment: Indeed.  People seem not to realize that (e.g.) "a" is a Unicode character.

Answer (score 6):

`"\u03C0"`

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3c0/index.htm

Answer (score 3):

If you want to write this to a file you can achieve it through Unicodes, below is an example of how,

```
import java.io.*;
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        BufferedWriter out = 
                    new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                          new FileOutputStream("out.txt"),"UTF8"));     

    out.write("alpha = \u03B1, beta = \u03B2 ,pi = \u03C0");
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}
}
```

out put : alpha = α, beta = β ,pi = π

Comment: ```out.write("alpha = α, beta = β, pi = π")``` seems more straightforward.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to use the value of PI, you can use `Math.PI` after importing Math class using `import java.lang.Math;`

Comment: That is not an answer to the question though. The question is about how to get the character symbol for π, not the value of pi.