# How to display PI symbol in Java?

Tags: java, character-encoding, pi

The objective here is simple, I want to display a pi symbol in a system output, like this, "π"

```
    String pi = "\u03c0";
    System.out.println (""+a+pi+"x^2 + " + b+pi+"x + " +c+ pi);
```

Comment: Just copy-paste the character in your question into Java source. (Make sure to save your files and compile them as UTF-8.

Comment: Read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089519/how-to-type-pi-in-java

Comment: Remember that the font for your console has to support that character in Unicode in the first place. Try changing your console font and encoding.

Comment: What is the problem? What happens when you run the code? The answers seem to tell you just to do what you are doing.

Answer (score 5):

Output to where?  the console?  The below should do that.

```
System.out.println("π");
```

Comment: Or `System.out.println("\u03c0")` if the source code is not in UTF-8.

Comment: Having the correct character in Java memory is only half the battle, you also need to get the output encoding right. For example, in Windows command line, you would `chcp 65001` and even change the font if it's still the default one.

Answer (score 4):

The `'π'` character corresponds to the code point of `03C0` - a valid point of the UNICODE-16, the encoding used by the Java source. Since the number of the code point fits in 16 bits, you can simply copy-paste the symbol into your Java source.

You can also use a UNICODE constant directly, like this:

```
System.out.println("\u03C0");
```

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089519/how-to-type-pi-in-java)

You need the unicode `\u03C0` this represents PI. (π)

So then you can just use

```
System.out.println("\u03C0");
```

Answer (score 1):

works for me

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("π");
    }

}
```

maybe you have an error in your character encoding of the sourcecode-file:
Ensure UTF-8 encoding in your source-file!

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
    System.out.println("\u03c0");
```