# Java can't handle π character

Tags: java, printing, pi

Reduced version of my current problem: I'm trying to print the character π in java, but when I do:

```
System.out.println("π");
```

All I get in the console is a question mark. I don't know why this happens and I haven't been able to fix it, hopefully someone will know how to. Thanks

Comment: Ensure your console can display unicode characters

Comment: Please give us more information about what console you're using (under which OS), how you're compiling, etc. (At the moment it *could* be that your text editor and compiler disagree, so you've got the wrong character in the compiled code - or it could be that it's the console.)

Comment: Why don't You use the ¶ (0xb6) from the Basic Latin character set? Every OS should be able to display this character set.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the escape character `\u03C0`. This [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089519/how-to-type-%CF%80-pi-in-java) is the same question.

Comment: If it's a duplicate, it's best not to answer it, but to wait for it to be closed as a duplicate. However, I don't think it actually *is* a duplicate, as I suspect it's about the console rather than getting the character itself.

Comment: @jonSkeet Thank you, I'm still relatively new to using Stack Overflow.

Comment: If the printing of `π` results in a `?`, the printing of `\u03C0` will most likely fail too.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your source code is writen in UTF-8.

You can also use a UNICODE constant directly, like this:

```
System.out.println("\u03C0");
```

Comment: I strongly suspect that this is actually about the console itself - we need more details from the OP.

Comment: Might be, cause I'm still getting the ? after trying System.out.println("\u03C0"); In that case, I guess I don't really need to do anything about this since I don't really need to print that pi symbol inscreen